# Passing data from PHP class to PHPExcel via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, oop, phpexcel

i got stuck with OOP PHP and json data. i'm not completely new to OOP, but i can't get my head around this. if anyone can please explain to me, would be great!

i have the following grid object in PHP:

```
    Class Grid {

        var $data;
        var $joins;
        var $fields;
        var $where;
        var $table;
        var $groupBy;
        var $having;
        var $limit;
        var $order_by;
        var $sort;
        var $security;
        var $set;
        var $sql;

....

        // loads data into the grid
        function load() {
    ...
            // setup the sql - bring it all together
            $sql = "
                SELECT $post[cols]
                FROM `$table`
                $joins
                $where
                $groupBy
                $having
                ORDER BY $order_by $sort
                $limit
            ";

            $this->sql = $sql;

            // execute the sql, get back a multi dimensial array
            $rows = $this->_queryMulti($sql);

            // form an array of the data to send back
            $data = array();
            $data['rows'] = array();
            foreach($rows as $i=>$row) {
                foreach($row as $col=>$cell) {
                    // use primary key if possible, other wise use index
                    $key = $primaryKey ? $row[$primaryKey] : $i;
                    // primary key has an _ infront becuase of google chrome re ordering JSON objects
                    //http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164
                    $data['rows']["_".$key][$col] = $cell;
                }
            }

    ...        
            $data['order_by'] = $order_by;
            $data['sort'] = $sort;
            $data['page'] = $page;
            $data['start'] = $startRow + 1;
            $data['end'] = $startRow + $nRowsShowing;
            $data['colData'] = $colData;

            $this->data = $data;
        }
```

and it's called by AJAX callgrid.php:

```
$grid->load();
        // here we need to add field in data[sql] = sql query, then we can pass it to toExcel() - how?
        echo json_encode($grid->data);
```

what i'm trying to get is to be able to export current sql query (it can be all or searched results) into Excel using PHPExcel. So i've got toExcel.php with function toexcel($query) - that will take a query and export it to excel.

now - HOW do i pass sql query from grid to toexcel via AJAX?

1. I understand that i need to add to $data():

   $data['sql'] = $sql;

what next?

---

UPDATE:
I'm using the following jquery grid:
http://square-bracket.com/openjs

I understand that PHPExcel should be initiated either by grid or jquery

Comment: Why through AJAX? Why not do it all within PHP?

Comment: because grid itself loads from ajax. so sql query will be formed only when called by ajax: `$(".grid.digital_edit").loadGrid({...})`

Comment: ok - i don't need to be stuck with AJAX. but how then anyway?

Comment: Instead of echoing `$grid->data` use it as input data for PHPExcel

Comment: @ Mchl - what do you mean "instead"?? then the grid wouldn't load. it should load in browser and still have capability of exporting to Excel... and i don't need it to export to Excel every time - only when user request, say, by pressing a button?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A general idea of what you could do:

Create a button e.g.

```
<a href="#" id="export">export to Excel</a>
```

Then in jquery you have to create something like:

```
var grid = $(".grid.digital_edit").loadGrid({...}); //or similar - what you did to load the data into the grid

$('#export').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "export_to_excel.php", // the url of the php file that will generate the excel file
        data: grid.getData(), //or similar - based on the grid's API
        success: function(response){
            window.location.href = response.url;
        }
    })

});
```

The file export_to_excel.php will contain the code that generates the excel file:

1. This is where you'll initiate the PHPExcel class and create a file e.g. new_excel.xls
2. In your response array the $response['url'] will contain the absolute url to the newly created file. (http://www.example.com/files/new_excel.xls)

It may sound too complex, but try to separate your goals and achieve one at a time. E.g.

1. Create the button.
2. Then try to make a simple AJAX call when hitting the button.
3. Then create your export_to_excel.php file and try to work with the PHPExcel class.
4. Create a sample excel file based on the tutorials found.
5. Create an excel file based on your own data, but hard-coded in the php file.
6. Create the correct AJAX call that sends the wanted data to a php file.
7. Catch the correct AJAX call.
8. Pass the data from the AJAX call to the PHPExcel class.
9. Create the excel file.
10. Send back the url to the excel file.
11. Redirect the user to the url of the excel file.

**EDIT**

To help you a bit more: You need only one PHP script/file. The same one will receive the AJAX call from the javascript file, will generate the excel file and will return/respond the file url to the javascript file(in that order). A simplified example would be:

```
<?php
//export_to_excel.php

$data = $_POST['data']; // get the data from the AJAX call - it's the "data: grid.getData()" line from above

//... format the received data properly for the PHPExcel class

// later on in the same file:
$xls = new PHPExcel();
$xls->loadData($formattedData); //I assume that there is a similar loadData() method
$xls->exportToFile('/vaw/www/example.com/public/files/new_excel.xls'); // I assume that there is an exportToFile() method

$response = array(
    'success' => true,
    'url' => 'http://www.example.com/files/new_excel.xls'
);

header('Content-type: application/json');

// and in the end you respond back to javascript the file location
echo json_encode($response);
```

And then in javascript you display the file with this line

```
window.location.href = response.url; //response.url is $response['url'] from the PHP script
```

Comment: Thanks Aletzo - I already have all the working php files - my problem is to interconnect them. so you suggesting that i could access sql query currently run by simply calling it to AJAX as data: grid.getData() - this getData() i create myself or you assume this function should be already available within the grid?

Comment: The grid.getData() part is javascript. The javascript library that you use in order to display the grid, _should_ have implemented already a method so that you may get the grid data (I called it getData). If not, you have to do it yourself, but usually every library has a similar method that you can use.

Comment: In javascript you have no access at all to the sql query, or to the PHPExcel class. That's why you have to make the AJAX call, which means that the javascript (client side) is asking the php (server side) to do something. The php will deal with the PHPExcel class, will generate the file and will tell javascript that "OK here is the url of the excel file that I created". Then javascript will show that url to the user.

Comment: I just think that what you are trying to do here, is solve 2-3 different problems simultaneously that you haven't solved before and that is too overwhelming for you. Posting a complete solution would take a couple of hours of coding, that I can not afford sadly. That's why, I suggest that you could identify each problem separately and solve it, and then combine all the solutions together.

Comment: i'm accepting this answer despite you ignoring my comments that i don't need help with PHP. i'm accepting it on the basis that the first part of your answer code actually lead me to the right direction. the actual answer i needed is - STORE GRID OBJECT IN A VAR AND THEN ACCESS IT'S OPTIONS WHERE NEEDED

Comment: I'm sorry for that. There is no need to accept it, really. I was just trying to help.

Comment: @aletzo: sorry for the answer, I try to use your code but the $_POST create an internal error 500, where i the mistake for you?the code is more or less you code...