# Download excel file with ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpexcel

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('TestMessages');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test_form_".date("Y-m-d_H:i:s").".xls");
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

When I call above code directly from the browser, the result file is downloaded. But if I make an ajax call to above code, I don't get the download prompt. I can see from console tab that the ajax call was successfully completed and a bunch of random characters is seen in the response data. I'm assuming that is the excel object.

Does anyone know how I can achieve the download excel feature using ajax? I don't want to refresh the page. When the user clicks on the "export" button, there should be an ajax call to the php file and prompt the user to download.

I reffer [Passing data from PHP class to PHPExcel via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209009/passing-data-from-php-class-to-phpexcel-via-ajax) but do not understand how to achieve my goal?

Comment: You can add a hidden iframe in the page. When the ajax call returns the url of the created data, use javascript to redirect the iframe to that url which automatically triggers the download action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue by following way.

add target=_blank in your ajax success function like below

```
success: function(){
  window.open('http://MY_URL','_blank' );
},
```

On success open new window with my_url.

Answer (score 5):

PHP

```
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);
ob_start();
$objWriter->save("php://output");
$xlsData = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$response =  array(
        'op' => 'ok',
        'file' => "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,".base64_encode($xlsData)
    );

die(json_encode($response));
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:"MY_URL.php",
    data: {},
    dataType:'json'
}).done(function(data){
    var $a = $("<a>");
    $a.attr("href",data.file);
    $("body").append($a);
    $a.attr("download","file.xls");
    $a[0].click();
    $a.remove();
});
```

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, I managed to solve my problem by using this method, so thank you and +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need Ajax.

Using javascript's `window.location.replace()` if you get an url which sends a file, it will prompt to be downloaded without redirecting the browser.

If you need to post data, you can create a hidden form with the fields set up the way you need them, make sure that the "target" attribute of the form is set to `"_BLANK"`, and then submit the form programatically.

**For first comment below :**

maybe try replacing :

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

with `readfile ($file_name);`

Comment: Can you give me some hint or example?

Comment: I implemented `readfile ($file_name);` but do not give me prompt.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just redirect to the page that downloaded the excel file when you click the button

Comment: I do not want to refresh page that's why I used ajax call.

Comment: then just use <a href="location" target="_blank"> instead

Comment: I do not want to open new tab or window just want to download popup on success response.